# how to save the time that user spent answering questions in my form to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a problem to save "time" to my database. The "time" I want to save is the time user spent on answering the question I made so then when they hit the submit button, the amount time they spent is saved to the database.

here is my javascript:

```
    var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
    var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var totalSeconds = 0;
    var secondLabel = document.getElementById("second");
    setInterval(setTime, 1000);

    function setTime()
    {
        ++totalSeconds;
        secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
        secondLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds);
        minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
    }

    function pad(val)
    {
        var valString = val + "";
        if(valString.length < 2)
        {
            return "0" + valString;
        }
        else
        {
            return valString;
        }
    }
```

this is how I call them:

```
<label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>
```

what i'm trying to achieve is to save the minuteslabel. If you have any suggestion, don't hesitate to reply. Thanks

Comment: How are you saving the seconds? This is not in this code.

Comment: add a focus handler to the first input on your form and start counting then (you can use setInterval to increment a value every second) and a sumbit handler to clear the first interval and grab the total value counted. Then you can send it with all your other data

Comment: @Jerodev this is the part to make the time is ticking from 0
ex : 00:00 when start (autostart when the page is open), then it will be 00:05 when 5 seconds are past

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how to do that? what im trying to save to database is the minutes label. so how do i pass the value to my database?

Comment: what exactly is the issue? retrieving the value? or posting it?

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak the issue is retrieving the value from javascript and saving it to databse. I have some questions which in a form and count up time running (in js) when the page is load. Let assume the time user take to answer the question is 8 minutes. So now, how do I can send the value (8 minutes) to my database along with the answer (in the question form)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you're printing the time in the screen already. If you're using form submission and not ajax, do the following:

```
<!-- In your view / html -->
<form ........ >
<input type="hidden" id="timeSpent" name="timeSpent">
.
. 
.

// In your Javascript
<script>
function setTime()
{
    ++totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
    secondLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
    document.getElementById("timeSpent").value = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60)) + pad(totalSeconds%60);
}
</script>
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but how can I save it to database if I don't pass it to php first?